# Why are clang versions so inconsistent with their speed?

Tags: c++, clang, llvm

I've written this simple program (in sum9.cpp) to test C++ runtime:

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>

typedef unsigned long long int big;

constexpr bool has9(big num) {
    while(num != 0) {
        int last = num % 10;
        if(last == 9) {
            return true;
        }
        num /= 10;
    }
    return false;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    if (argc < 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Must provide an upper limit.\n");
        return 1;
    }
    big ubound;
    if (sscanf(argv[1], "%llu", &ubound) != 1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not read an integer from argv[1].\n");
    }
    big sum = 0;
    for (big i = 0; i < ubound; ++ i) {
        if (has9(i)) {
            sum += i;
        }
    }
    printf("%llu\n", sum);
    return 0;
}
```

I downloaded both clang 6 and clang 10 from [this page](https://releases.llvm.org/download.html). I compiled the file with `clang++-6 -Ofast -march=core2 sum9.cpp -o sum9-c6` and `clang++-10 -Ofast -march-core2 sum9.cpp -o sum9-c10`. Then, I timed them with `time ./sum9-c6 1000000000` and `time ./sum9-c10 1000000000`. To my surprise, clang 6 had a time of 8.65 seconds on average while clang-10 had a time of 9.74s on average. For reference, an equivalent rust program takes around 8.57 seconds when compiled with `-C target-cpu=core2`. However, when I compile with `-march=native` instead of `-march=core2`, clang 10 suddenly takes only 8.09 seconds to run while clang 6 takes 8.28 seconds to run. Why does this happen, and can I make clang 10 not take so long when not using `-march=native`?

Here are the versions:

```
clang version 10.0.0 
Target: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
```

```
clang version 6.0.1 (tags/RELEASE_601/final)
Target: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
```

Here are continuously run benchmarks for clang10 and clang6 with `-march=core2`:

```
clang10
real    0m9.738s

clang6
real    0m8.561s

clang10
real    0m9.732s

clang6
real    0m8.553s

clang10
real    0m9.737s

clang6
real    0m8.582s

clang10
real    0m9.741s

clang6
real    0m8.579s

clang10
real    0m9.736s

clang6
real    0m8.582s

clang10
real    0m9.736s

clang6
real    0m8.580s

clang10
real    0m9.738s

clang6
real    0m8.564s

clang10
real    0m9.725s

clang6
real    0m8.569s

clang10
real    0m9.729s

clang6
real    0m8.559s

clang10
real    0m9.730s

clang6
real    0m8.574s
```

Here are benchmarks for `-march=native` (notice how clang10 is now suddenly faster):

```
clang10
real    0m8.09s

clang6
real    0m8.28s

clang10
real    0m8.09s

clang6
real    0m8.28s

clang10
real    0m8.08s

clang6
real    0m8.27s

clang10
real    0m8.09s

clang6
real    0m8.27s

clang10
real    0m8.07s

clang6
real    0m8.27s

clang10
real    0m8.08s

clang6
real    0m8.28s

clang10
real    0m8.08s

clang6
real    0m8.27s

clang10
real    0m8.09s

clang6
real    0m8.29s

clang10
real    0m8.08s

clang6
real    0m8.28s

clang10
real    0m8.07s

clang6
real    0m8.27s
```

Comment: These benchmarks are completely meaningless unless you've done multiple runs in random order to account for the sort of variation you get on modern CPUs. Often the second test to run will go faster simply because the CPU is throttled up speed-wise to "turbo" mode. If you have the option, pin your CPU at a constant speed and aggregate the results of many, many tests to know more accurately. You'll want at least five minutes of continuous testing to have any reasonable benchmark here, not just a quick blip where the CPU barely heats up.

Comment: @tadman I've run 10 benchmarks continuously, alternating between clang10 and clang6, and I've included the benchmarks in my post. I will work on getting benchmarks for `-march=native`.

Comment: @DeducibleSteak I've included benchmarks for `-march=native`. My question is mainly about why clang10 is so much slower than clang6 with no `-march` specified and `-march=core2`, but is suddenly faster with `-march=native` on both. I don't want to have two different versions of clang that I have to keep toggling between when I want to optimize my performance.

Comment: I'm running an Intel Xeon CPU.

Comment: When I first read this question, I expected to see differences in speed of double, triple, or an order of magnitude.  But you're posting figures that suggest differences of 12 percent or less.  Frankly, I would expect that amount of variation.

Comment: I'm not talking about the variation between core2 and native, I'm talking about how clang10 went from much worse than clang6 to better than clang6. How can I ensure that I get optimal speeds when compiling both non-specialized binaries and ones specialized for my native cpu?

Comment: Clang 6's core2 code is faster than clang 10's core2 code by a significant margin. Therefore, I'd expect clang 6's native code to also be faster than clang 10's native code. However, that is clearly not the case as shown by the benchmarks. This is very suboptimal, as I'd have to maintain 2 versions of a compiler: one for compiling binaries that are compatible with many cpus, and one for compiling binaries for my native cpu. Why is this behavior exhibited and can I get rid of this inconsistency?

Comment: I don't think you're understanding. I don't care about the fact that the native code is faster than the non-native code. I'd be surprised if it didn't. I care about the fact that clang10 is faster than clang6 in some cases but not in other cases.

Comment: clang10 is also slower than clang6 when no `-march` is specified for either, which is a major issue. I just used core2 as an example.